# Add expires headers. Yslow and headers from debugger have different answers

Tags: apache, http-headers, yslow

I am using Yslow to check my site performance.

The problem is that Yslow show different result from headers that I see in debugger.
In debugger it looks like Expires headers are set (and I configured apache to do so).
You see that `Date` and `Expires` headers are different
 [image]

But Yslow tells me something else.[image]

The situation is the same with all files.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [yslow still not giving me an A for expires header in apache httpd even though I added them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517083/yslow-still-not-giving-me-an-a-for-expires-header-in-apache-httpd-even-though-i)